# Container group results in a "No more IP addresses available on network" error

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

I'm unable to create the container group like the one in the screenshot below:

[image]

I get the following error:

```
Failure message: Resource CREATE failed: Error: Resource CREATE failed:  
Error: Resource CREATE failed: IpAddressGenerationFailureClient: No more IP 
addresses available on network a2e7d252-f230-4136-b809-6ba569cf4770.
```

By setting a unique host name for the container group, the group should then be accessible using that name without the requirement of allocating a public IP address to the group, correct?

Thus, this error message doesn't make sense to me. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting. I'm from the IBM Containers team and we noticed this as well starting around 4:30am this morning eastern time. We have resolved the issue with IP allocations and you should have success again!